Getting some gradle related issue in my Flutter App
The app was running well but today on start this are the error it throws. No idea what those meant searched online but couldn't fix with any related issue solution.
Here is my the Error code
> Failed to transform appcompat-resources-1.7.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\lenovo\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\e9f9f01bedba15c5f2942d36d93237e4\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.7.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.7.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\lenovo\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c2c5424967df4e2b2c06cf59e0c0f144\transformed\appcompat-1.7.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 16s


Flutter Doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4037], locale en-IN)
[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✗] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    ✗ Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.92.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

If any other files are required i can provide those.
I have tried searching for solution, found some but there seems to be no change. The end goal is basically running the application.
